# Update scatter plot color in slider (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider, scatter-plot

I have defined a scatter 3d plot `p = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=colors, s=10, alpha=0.5)`. I would like to modify the color of said scatter plot using a slider. The `colors` is a list of float. I basically have a light source moving around with an angle `theta` and `phi` and I want the scatter plot to change color depending on that.

For the moment I simply `remove` the scatter plot and re-plot it but I find this highly inefficient. I know that in Matplotlib I can use `rcParameters` to modify arguments of objects like `rcParam['figure.figsize']`. However, when I try the color doesn't change and I often get a `incorrect RGB value` error.

So far here is the update function I am using

```
# Set figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_axis_off() # remove axis 

particles_scatter = ax.scatter(x_filtered, y_filtered, z_filtered, c=colors, s=radius_particles, alpha=0.5) # plot particles

# Set sliders to change light source position

theta_slider_ax = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
theta_slider = Slider(theta_slider_ax, 'Theta', 0, 2 * np.pi, valinit=0)
phi_slider_ax = plt.axes([0.25, 0.05, 0.65, 0.03])
phi_slider = Slider(phi_slider_ax, 'Phi', 0, np.pi, valinit=0)

def update(val):
    theta = theta_slider.val
    phi = phi_slider.val
    
    # the light source position changes
    x = r_light * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
    y = r_light * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
    z = r_light * np.cos(phi)

    global colors, particles_scatter
    light_pos  = np.array([x, y, z])
    colors = calculate_scattering(num_particles_effective,x_filtered,y_filtered,z_filtered,light_pos) # calculate the new color of the scatter plot according to the new light source position.
    particles_scatter.remove()
    particles_scatter = ax.scatter(x_filtered, y_filtered, z_filtered, c=colors, s=radius_particles, alpha=0.5) # re-plot scatter plot

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

theta_slider.on_changed(update)
phi_slider.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

And this is how I calculate the new color of my scatter plot:

```
# Generate random positions for particles in atmosphere
theta = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, num_particles)
phi = np.random.uniform(0, np.pi, num_particles)
r = radius_atmosphere * np.cbrt(np.random.uniform(0, 1, num_particles))
x = r * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
y = r * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
z = r * np.cos(phi)

# Removes particles if they are inside the radius of the planet
indices = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2) > radius_planet
x_filtered = x[indices]
y_filtered = y[indices]
z_filtered = z[indices]

num_particles_effective = len(x_filtered)

# Calculate scattering
def calculate_scattering(num_particles,x_particles,y_particles,z_particles,light_pos):
    colors = []
    for i in range(num_particles_effective):
        pos = np.array([x_particles[i], y_particles[i], z_particles[i]])
        direction = pos - light_pos
        direction = direction / np.linalg.norm(direction)
        angle = np.arccos(np.dot(direction, np.array([0, 0, 1])))
        color = np.exp(-0.5*(angle/0.2)**2)
        colors.append(color)
    return colors

colors = calculate_scattering(num_particles_effective,x_filtered,y_filtered,z_filtered,light_pos)
```